# Why do I get different output signals when I merge these two circuits together?

Tags: filter, ltspice

The circuit below has an amplifier, a sixth order filter, a virtual ground (2.5 V) block, a band pass filter (center frequency of 10 kHz) and a decaying peak detector. If the microphone voltage is replaced by a sine wave with 10 kHz frequency the output signal looks like the red curve in image 3. Takes a bit to load the plot in LTspice.

[image]

[image]

[image]

The circuit below is almost the same as the above, but the input signal originates from an animal sound and there's no band pass filter. The output signal of this circuit is the green curve. This circuit is faster to load than the previous circuit for some reason.

[image]

[image]

[image]

If I merge the two circuits together I get this:

[image]

It's pretty much the same as the circuits above, the input signal is the one from the animal sound.

[image]

Works fine here, the block with the band pass filter the output signal is 2.5 V because the input signals is in the cut region.

Now if I put a pure sine wave with 10 kHz (and amplitude 0.1 V) as input the simulations just ends in 135 us, it never leaves here.

[image]

Why does this happen and how can I avoid it?

Comment: Your schematic is as big as my neighborhood with tiny parts that are hard to see because all the parts are Too Far Apart!

Comment: Click and zoom in

Comment: Good idea!  https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5ppy.png

Comment: The spread out schematic with the tiny parts also does not fit on the screen of the simulator.

Comment: I still can't read the nets when zoomed in, post a higher res pic. You may have to make a pano of a couple screenshots

Comment: About the settling time it's a matter of time scale: in the 1st simulation you're using tens of ms, in the 2nd hundreds of ms, so it appears as if it's faster in the 2nd. About the last part, try replacing the opamps with the `[Opamps]/UniversalOpamp3a` (or `3b`), the model for the TLV is probably not very good. Adjust parameters as needed. And why on earth would you generate those godawful symbols instead of using the much MUCH friendlier `[Opamps]/opamp2` symbol?